# regex remove characters from string

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to remove certain data from a string using regular expression.
say i have a string: "Name (birthyear) [data] "
the result i want: "Name birthyear"

what i have right now:

```
data = data.replaceAll("((?s)(<|\\[).*?(>|\\]))","");
```

which gives the result:
"Name (birthyear)"

what would i need to add to this regex to also remove the '(' and ')'?

I only want to use one regex for this, because the method will be used to replace a huge amount of data (+-20m lines)

Comment: You may try `.replaceAll("(?s)[<(\\[].*?[>\\])]","")`. Or, if other delimiters can appear inside others, `"(?s)<[^>]*>|\\[[^\\]]*]|\\([^)]*\\)"`

Comment: `return input.substring(0,input.indexOf(" "))+" "+input.substring(input.indexOf("("),input.lastIndexOf(")"));` with assumption that `(` and `)` are present no where else.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this also removes the data inside the '(' ')'

Comment: Regex are nice to play with, but if the formula is simple enough or the amount of data to parse big enough, and speed is important, then try to avoid them, and use plain string logic. This coming from a big fan or regexes !

Comment: But your regex does it, too. If you need what is inside, use a capturing group in the pattern and backreferences in the replacement. See https://regex101.com/r/ffTHrS/1 or https://regex101.com/r/o7nOem/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my regex removes everything inside the '[' ']' and '<' '>', im not trying to do the same for '(' ')'

Comment: So, just remove the two symbols? [`(?s)[<\[].*?[>\]]|[()]+`](https://regex101.com/r/o7nOem/2).

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regex for this:

```
// Assuming ( and ) are present in the string, in that order.
int openingBracket = data.indexOf('(');
int closingBracket = data.indexOf(')', openingBracket);
data = new StringBuilder(closingBracket - 1)
  // The bit up to (but not including) the (
  .append(data, 0, openingBracket)
  // The bit after the (, up to the ).
  .append(data, openingBracket + 1, closingBracket)
  .toString();
```

Using basic string operations like this will almost always be faster than using a regular expression: internally, the regex engine has to use these sorts of operations to manipulate the strings too. Thus, a regex-based implementation can only be "no less complicated" than the above.

([An informal benchmark](http://ideone.com/bG8tp3) shows my approach to be roughly 10 times faster than Kent's answer).

The power of regular expressions comes from the conciseness with which you can represent the pattern that you are searching for, not from their speed.

But that conciseness can be a curse as well as a blessing: it is easy to construct a regular expression that leaves you scratching your head as to how it works. Using more verbose code, as above, might help, because you can debug this a lot more easily: you can stop on each line and see how the subexpressions evaluate.

Ultimately, it's a balance: sometimes regular expressions are the right tool, sometimes they're not. You should definitely be aware of the alternatives, and weigh their relative merits for your particular application.

Comment: please note that i will use this code to scan over 20 million lines, which is why i will need to use a regex

Comment: @user3499284 regexes are *slow*; or, at least, they're not going to be any faster than using basic string operations, because they use basic string operations themselves. I'd encourage you to benchmark this approach against a regex-based approach to see this.

Comment: Yes, but not “probably”, “assuredly”!

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes, that's why I concur with you, and even suggested you used the word “assuredly” instead of the too cautious “probably” :)

Comment: would this also be a lot faster if i add more characters to look for, like tabs, spaces etc?

Comment: @user3499284 possibly, you'd need to try it for yourself. That's not the question you asked, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
String data = "Name (birthyear) [data] ";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("([^(]+)[(]([^)]+)[)].*","$1$2"));
```

this prints:

```
Name birthyear
```

#### update:

- we take two groups from the input string:`$1$2`
- group1: from beginning till the first open-bracket char(exclusive), which would be: `Name+space`
- group2: after the open bracket, we take 1st char till the last non-close-bracket char, which is `birthyear`, and we skip all other chars.

Comment: could you break down the regex and explain what each part does?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

- Find: `\(([^)]+)\)\s*[<\\[].+?[>\\]]`
- Replace: `$1`

**Explanation:**

```
\(      : open parenthesis
([^)]+) : group 1, not a close parenthesis
\)      : a close parenthesis
\s*     : 0 or more spaces
[<\\[]  : < or [
.+?     : 1 or more character non greedy
[>\\]]  : > or ]
```